# How do I beat the seahorses?

Tags: candy-box-2

In the sea level, I do ok until I reach the seahorses. They fire projectiles but never attack, and never go away. How do I kill them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can kill them with Red enchanted leather gloves or fireballs.

Comment: or the (enchanted) monkey wizard staff

Comment: Or regular monkey wizard staff

Answer (score 3):

You can defeat them by using the fireball spell or by using the monkey wizard staff.

Answer (score 1):

use the monkey wizard staff and hide at the bottom. your staff will track the enemy

Answer (score 0):

you can use kill them with the fireball spell

Answer (score 0):

you can use black demons spell